# Hide and Show TextBox in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to hide and show box using following code. This work but box is displayed by default. Can I hide the box and only display on click? Currently onclick works to hide the box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function display(id) {
var obj = document.getElementById(id)
if (obj.style.display == "none") {
obj.style.display = "block"
    }
else {
    obj.style.display = "none"
    }
return false
}
</script>

 <form>
<input type="button" value="Customize" onclick="display('box1_<?=$pd_id?>')">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What precise element are you clicking to show which element? Hint: JavaScript is *client-side*, PHP is *server-side*, and almost always irrelevant to HTML, CSS and JavaScript questions. When showing HTML code for JavaScript (and seriously, kudos for showing code!), please show the HTML that the browser sees (view source or in the DOM from the developer tools), *not* the PHP script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

addthe following either in the stylesheet or inline styling

```
style="display: none;"
```

Answer (score 3):

1) Sure just add a style or css class to the object.

```
<input type="button" style="display:none" value="Customize" onclick="display()">
```

2) Just exact the element from the event:

```
   function display(evnt) {
    var obj = evnt.target;
    obj.style.display = (obj.style.display === 'none') ? 'block' : 'none'; // (cond) ? <do> : <else>
}
```

jsFiddle example working example (ignore the getDocument line and of course once it hidden you can't see it anymore..;)

http://jsfiddle.net/BRa9n/

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS, and add: `<div id="your_box" style="display:none;"></div>` initially it will be hidden and `onclick()` change the attribute to `display:block`

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the box hidden with `'visibility: hidden' or 'display: none'` and then onclik change the property to `visibility = 'visible';`

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can use `object.style.visibility="hidden"` to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It is, of course, possible to do this without JavaScript (albeit the HTML becomes a little more complex, and relies upon support for the `:checked` pseudo-selector. Given the HTML:

```
<form>
    <label class="button" for="customize">Customize</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="customize" />
    <input id="submit" />
</form>
```

And the CSS:

```
label.button {
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}

#customize {
    display: none;
}

#customize + #submit {
    display: none;
}

#customize:checked + #submit {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p6Mgg/).

References:

- [`:checked` pseudo-selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3achecked).
- [`:checked` pseudo-selector compatibility](http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/#t60).